# Symfony's locateResource not working as expected

Tags: php, symfony

I've been trying to access a static text file in the app/Resources directory by using Symfony Kernel `locateResource` method. According to [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html) and [this](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.html#method_locateResource), it should work with the following code:

```
 $kernel = $this->get('kernel');
 $path = $kernel->locateResource('@AppBundle/Resources/file/app_version.txt');
```

It throws an Exception with message '*Unable to find file*', even though the file exists inside the folder named 'file'.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your file is in `app/Ressources` and you are telling **Symfony** to look in `src/AppBundle/Ressources` which is definitely not the same.

Move the file to the correct location (*that is, effectively, in the bundle*) and it will work as expected.

More info on the directory structure here : https://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_architecture.html